# JSON Issue - how to fix that?

Tags: java, android, json

This is my code for getting the data from `JSON`, it will contain only one row,
but it will give output for only "pro_name" for left of the values it will give just dots(......).

```
package com.example.sh_enterprises;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Detailes extends AppCompatActivity {



    //this is the JSON Data URL
    //make sure you are using the correct ip else it will not work
    public  static  String URL_PRODUCTS, pass1,pass2 ;
    public static String ptopic,psubcode;
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    //a list to store all the products
    List<pro_data> productList;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailes);
        Intent i = getIntent();

        pass1 = i.getStringExtra("pro_id");

        //Toast.makeText(this,"HI THIS IS "+pass,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //URL_PRODUCTS = "https://premnathindia.000webhostapp.com/Api.php?p1="+pass;
        URL_PRODUCTS = "http://192.168.225.25/prem/Api.php?p1="+pass1+"&p2=det";


        Toast.makeText(this, URL_PRODUCTS, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        //this method will fetch and parse json
        //to display it in recyclerview
        loadProducts();
    }

    private void loadProducts() {

        prefConfig product = new prefConfig(this);
        String str = product.read_ret_id();
        Toast.makeText(this,str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        /*
        * Creating a String Request
        * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
        * The URL is defined in the second parameter
        * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
        * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
        * */
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);


                                product.getString("pro_id");

                                String st;

                                TextView a = findViewById(R.id.pro_name);
                                TextView b = findViewById(R.id.weight);
                                TextView c = findViewById(R.id.base_amount);
                                TextView d = findViewById(R.id.mass_amonut);
                                TextView e = findViewById(R.id.brand);
                                TextView f = findViewById(R.id.catogery);

                                String st1 = product.getString("pro_name");
                                a.setText(st1);

                                st = product.getString("weight");
                                b.setText(st);

                                st = product.getString("total_amount");
                                d.setText(st);

                                //st = product.getString("pro_img_url");

                                st = product.getString("base_amount");
                                c.setText(st);

                                //st = product.getString("disc");

                                st = product.getString("brands");
                                e.setText(st);

                                st = product.getString("categories");
                                f.setText(st);
                            }



                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);

    }

    public void downme_ooi(View view) {
        String pro_id = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Detailes.class);
        i.putExtra("pro_id",pro_id);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void go_back(View view) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add to your question stack trace and example `JSON` payload?

Comment: don't link to external resources, as they may become inaccessible. Instead, paste the relevant part of your code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I made the Mistake that  in TextView I put the text as password .